# Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE] on real device

Tags: android, android-launcher

I'm trying to run my custom launcher3 apk from my android studio to onePlus mobile phone.Its API level is 23. this app works fine Up to level 22 but always getting error Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_VERSION_DOWNGRADE] on API level 23 and shows popup that uninstall the existing app. and infect this apk is not already installed. and when i tried with pressing OK button the it shows DELETE FAILED INTERNAL ERROR . I'm not getting the any solution. please help me. I tried to change the versionCode, VersionName API Level etc. but no solution. here is my gradle file

```html
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.android.launcher3"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile project(':wallpaperpick')
    compile 'com.github.yukuku:ambilwarna:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Comment: do you have multiple accounts on this device? May be there is already installed app on one of them

Comment: no sir
not any other account or installation

Comment: In your manifest increase the versionCode of new app, its not the issue of api level

Comment: not worked for me. or tell me what should enter new code ?

Comment: Try to uninstall App manually in your real device and try to run again.

Answer (score 6):

Try `adb install -r -d ${YOUR_APK_FILE_PATH}` to install.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall app from all the users before installing it again.
for Example:
Normal mode,
Guest user mode,
And also from work profile if it is in your phone.

After this app will install successfully.
I hope this will help.